# How to check if link is in same domain? and load then the link in same tab

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a angular 8 applicaiton.

And I have link. For exmaple: www.ad.nl. And then the link will redirect you to a new tab.

But if the link is in the same doman as website, in this case: localhost: http://localhost:4200/gezondheid/Measurement/actieindex

Then the link as to be loaded in same tab. So not different tab.

so this is function for external link:

```
@Input() activities: Activity[];

 isExternalLink(link: string): boolean {
    const currentHost = window.location.hostname;
    const linkHost = link.replace(/^http?:\/\/([^\/]*)\/.*/, (match, g1) => g1);
    return currentHost !== linkHost;
  }

  getRouterLink(link: string): string {
    return '/' + link;
  }
```

and this is the template:

```
  <a
      *ngIf="activity.link; else nolink"
      [href]="activity.link"
      [attr.target]="isExternalLink(activity.link) ? '_blank' : null"
      [attr.rel]="isExternalLink(activity.link) ? 'noopener noreferrer' : null"
    >
```

But so how to make it work if the link is in the same domain as the site , that it will not be loaded in extern tab, but in the same tab. Because now: http://localhost:4200/gezondheid/Measurement/actieindex will be loaded in saperate tab and not the same tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should be enough:

```js
isExternalLink(link: string): boolean {
    const currentHost = window.location.hostname;
    return !linkHost.includes(currentHost);
  }
```

For example, for this page (Stack Overflow) **window.location.hostname** returns **"stackoverflow.com"**. If you have link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/", your method would return **false**. In other case, let's say "https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript&oq=javascript&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3.2657j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8", it would return **true**